# Reading data in Zeppelin through cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a problem with a table in Cassandra.

```
CREATE TABLE tfm.foehis (hooe text, hodtac int, hohrac int, hoclic text,    hocdan text, hocdrs text, hocdsl text, hocol text, hocpny text, hodesf text, hodtcl int, hodtcm int, hodtea int, hodtra int, hodtrc int, hodtto date, hodtua int, hohrcl int, hohrcm int, hohrea int, hohrra int, hohrrc int, hohrua int, holinh text, holinr int, honrac int, honumr int, hoobs text, hotdsc int, hotour text, hotpac text, housca text, houscl text, huscm text, housea text, houser text, housra text, housrc text,PRIMARY KEY ((hooe, hodtac, hohrac), hoclic)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (hoclic ASC)
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

when I try to do a query appears some errors.

```
cqlsh> select housca from tfm.foehis where hoclic=1101;
```

`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Invalid INTEGER constant (1101) for "hoclic" of type text"`

```
cqlsh> select housca from tfm.foehis where hoclic=MOBIDI;
```

`SyntaxException: line 1:49 no viable alternative at input ';' (...from tfm.foehis where hoclic=[MOBIDI];)`

```
cqlsh> select * from tfm.foehis where hoclic=MOBIDI;
```

`SyntaxException: line 1:44 no viable alternative at input ';' (...from 
tfm.foehis where hoclic=[MOBIDI];)`

```
cqlsh> select * from tfm.foehis where hoclic=1101;
```

`InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]    message="Invalid INTEGER constant (1101) for "hoclic" of type text"`

Even 1101 and MOBIDI are values of `hoclic`.

In  Zeppelin when I use `select * from tfm.foehis;` appear all data and I can make the graphics that I want, but when I introduce this new statement `select * from tfm.foehis where hoclic="${CLIENT=1101|MOBIDI}";`

appear this error.

`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:46 no viable 
alternative at input ';' (...from tfm.foehis where hoclic=["singl]e";)
at 
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:58)
at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError.copy(SyntaxError.java:24)
...`

I think the problems is the definition of the primary key of the table, but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text fields must be included into single quotes, not into the double quotes! And didn't used without quotes at all - as in your examples...

Your examples should be written as

```
select housca from tfm.foehis where hoclic='1101';
select housca from tfm.foehis where hoclic='MOBIDI';
```

See the [definition of CQL literals](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/valid_literal_r.html).

Comment: Thank you, but I need to add at the end of the line ALLOW FILTERING. Is that normal?.

Comment: Ah, sorry - didn’t notice that... No, that’s not normal. Your query must select by partition/primary key...